# Can a SharePoint lookup field be pointed to anything other than a text field?

Tags: sharepoint, lookupfield

A lookup field declared in a feature and using the ShowField attribute to point to a numeric column in the target list (Type="Number") doesn't persist the user's selection. Changing the target field to Type="Text" and everything works fine.

Are there any known limitations to the types of fields a lookup field can be pointed at?